# Wow.js animation hiding element without padding

Tags: javascript, css-animations, wow.js

I installed [WOW.js](https://github.com/matthieua/WOW) (master version).
It works as attended on any content but the logo.

When I apply any transition to my site logo (inside the navbar, at the top of the viewport), I have this behaviour:

- As is, It is not working. Logo with wow class is not visible, I get this HTML after loading the page.

  `<span class="t2g-logo animated wow fadeInDown" style="visibility: hidden; animation-name: none;">2</span>`
- When I put a padding-top **>= 0.4 em**, it works as expected and I get this HTML after loading the page.

  `<span id="t2g-logo-2" class="t2g-logo  wow fadeInDown animated" 
          style="visibility: visible; animation-name: fadeInDown;">2</span>`

My markup is quite simple:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
      <span class="t2g-logo">Trip</span>
      <span class="t2g-logo wow fadeInDown">2</span>
      <span class="t2g-logo wow fadeIn">Go</span>
</a>
```

And the WOW initialization is inside \ like this:

```
<script>
    new WOW().init();
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated!

I created a fiddle to reproduce it: http://jsfiddle.net/andreav/9n74Le1t/

Try increasing padding-top to 0.4em and it will start working.